# Dynamically changing <div> content on link click with PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, dynamic

I have an area on my webpage that is populated by different `<div>` containers of information. When a link in my navigation bar is pressed, one `<div>` will fade out and another will fade in. What I'd like to do is have one of these content `<div>`'s filled with dynamic information, and when a link is pressed on another one of the "pages" it would change which database to load the information from and then display, or fade in, that `<div>` with the new information.

Sudo:

```
<a href = "#" onClick = "changeContent('dynamicDiv'); [Set which database to load the information from]; "> View information </a>

<div id = "dynamicDiv">
<?php include 'file.php' ?>
</div>
```

file.php

```
**Find which database to load information from and display content**
```

I thought about using $GLOBAL vars, but I'm not sure how to set those from a link, and also it wouldn't reload the div content.

I also considered using a form, but I'm not sure of the "correct" way of doing this would be, and also when the page is reloaded the `<div>` that is displayed by default would be loaded, not the `<div id = "dynamicDiv>`

Any suggestions/ideas are very much welcomed....

Comment: So you are getting any error while executing this?

Comment: You need to use an AJAX call to fetch the new content to load, then simply replace the div's contents with the result of that call. The only other option is a full-blown server roundtrip, reload/rebuild the whole page, and pass the ID of the content to load as a query parameter, e.g. `yourpage.php?file_to_include=XXX`.

Comment: @ArpitSrivastava Oh, that was just to further explain what I'm trying to do. I'm really not sure exactly where to start with this

Comment: Then you call that php file using `AJAX` or `.load` function of Jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you should use ajax.

AJAX is used for changing the page content from server without reloading the page.

You can use this [JQUERY AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) And [JQUERY LOAD](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#changediv").load("load.php?id=1");

})
```

in load.php
    $id=$_GET['id'];

```
// use that id for dynamic query in database
$query="SELECT *.....";
$result=mysql_query($query);
echo mysql_fetch_array($result);//somthing like that
```

All the word echoed in php become response in ajax.

Comment: Alright, i'll start looking into ajax. Now in my load.php file, the database to load the information will change based off which link is clicked (the links are also dynamic). Is there a way for me to pass that database name to the load.php using this?

Comment: Maybe when the link is clicked I could set a global variable that read in load.php? Not sure if this is correct though.

Comment: Thanks, once I do a little more reading, I think I'll have it figured out.